# GraphQL / Relay - optimisticResponse isn't propagating as I had hoped

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

In the mutation below I'm updating the `avatarId` for a person and I would like the new image**Url** to propagate everywhere it's needed, namely the `<UserAvatar />` component which can be in a lot of components on the same page.

I know this new URL before ever hitting the UpdatePersonMutation so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Do I need to involve the store and / or use `optimisticUpdater`, and / or use subscriptions to get a new avatar image to show up everywhere instantly?

```
import { commitMutation } from 'react-relay';
import graphql from 'babel-plugin-relay/macro';
import modernEnvironment from '../Environment';

const mutation = graphql`
  mutation UpdatePersonMutation($input: UpdatePersonInput!) {
    updatePerson(input: $input) {
      imageByAvatarId {
        id
        imageUrl // I know this before I ever reach this mutation
      }
      person {
        id
        avatarId
      }
    }
  }
`;

const commit = (payload, callback) => {
  const input = {
    id: payload.id,
    personPatch: {
      avatarId: payload.avatarId,
    },
  };
  return commitMutation(modernEnvironment, {
    mutation,
    variables: {
      input,
    },
    optimisticResponse: {
      updatePerson: {
        imageByAvatarId: {
          id: payload.imageId,
          imageUrl: payload.imageUrl,
        },
        person: {
          id: payload.id,
          avatarId: payload.avatarId,
        },
      },
    },
    onCompleted: response => {
      callback(response);
    },
    onError: error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
};

export default commit;
```